# CoreData - Populate tableview with NSManagedObjects but save only one

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3

I'm busy creating an iOS app in Swift 3 for iOS 8+ with CoreData.

I've a tableview with tasks. The tasks are retrieved from an API and each task from the JSON is inserted in a new NSManagedObject "Task". All these "Task" NSManagedObjects are stored in an array so that I have an array with all the "Task" objects from the JSON. Then I populate the tableview with that array of "Task" NSManagedObjects. But, when a user taps on a row, that single "Task" object have to be saved in CoreData (in the "Task" entity).

How can I populate the tableview with "Task" NSManagedObjects without saving all the tasks but only the one that the user taps?

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an intermediate custom struct.

- Parse the JSON into a custom struct.
- Use this struct as model for the table view.
- When the user taps a row map the struct instance to `NSManagedObject` and save it.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically map the struct instance to NSManagedObject, with the relationships in it? Or do I have to do it manually for each value?

Comment: You have to do it programmatically. There are third party mapper libraries but I doubt the benefit because technically they do it *manually*, too